# Is the Kronecker or Hadamard product of many Positive Semi-Definite Hermitian matrices also PSD Hermitian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

If I have $n$ Hermitian Positive Semi-Definite matrices $A_1, A_2 ... A_n$, does there exist any type of product (viz. Kronecker, Hadamard, Tracy-Singh, etc.) that gives back a  Hermitian Positive Semi-Definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kronecker product always works, because the eigenvalues of the product are necessarily non-negative. The Schur product (aka Hadamard) works, by a theorem of Schur.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote a small code to generate a 100 random PSDH matrices, and do the product and check. It worked but I was looking to make sure it was mathematically sound :)